# Help identifying this WW1 badge

Tags: world-war-one, identification

Can anyone help identifying this badge:

[image: badge]

The back reads: Pte G E Thornton from R'dents T'morel and district on his return from France.  1919

Comment: It looks like a '_return fob_' that was pretested to Private G E Thornton by the residents of Tannymorel in Queensland on his return at the end of the First World War.  I'll post an answer later if I can identify the other elements of the the fob (or perhaps someone else can).

Comment: Wowee that was quick. Thank you very much. Any other information would be welcome

Answer (score 8):

As I said in the comments, this looks like a '*return fob*' that was presented to Private G E Thornton by the residents of Tannymorel in Queensland on his return at the end of the First World War.

The enamel green and white badge in the centre looks like the [Unit Colour Patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_Colour_Patch) of the [2nd Light Horse regiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2nd_Light_Horse_Regiment_(Australia)):

[image: 2nd Light Horse Unit Colour Patch]

(although the badge on your return tag appears inverted, which may have some significance that I'm unaware of)

The 2nd Light Horse were a mounted infantry regiment raised in Queensland.

---

Based on this, I think you may have a badge that was given to George Edward THORNTON, Service Number 2331.  His [service record](https://recordsearch.naa.gov.au/SearchNRetrieve/Interface/ViewImage.aspx?B=8390425) is available from the national Archives of Australia.  He was taken on the strength of the [4th Anzac Battalion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4th_Battalion_(Australia)) on 30 December 1917 and served on the Western Front in France.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.  That has been very helpful